# iPhone storage increasing over time

Tags: iphone, storage

My iPhone 5s storage increases for some reason. It used to have 4.3 gb yesterday and now it’s 7.48 gb! I didn’t do much. My photos are still there. I’m scared. What do I do and why is it happening?

Also system is decreasing size.[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential reasons for this.

- If you installed a system update, the update data will be removed post update which can result in a large amount of space being.
- Apple have begun to implement several space saving features into iOS, which offload unneeded content to iCloud Drive or just remove it.
- You may have removed some optional system content, such as dictionaries, which freed up space.
- Rebooting your iOS device can sometimes free up some space, as iOS is based off of BSD so logs and temporary data may be expunged on reboot.

Comment: I did get a new Apple ID. I saw my iCloud Drive having a percentage.

Comment: That also may have had an effect, changing your Apple ID may have dumped system files relating to your old Apple ID that were no longer required/used.